# Update multiple Tabs using apps script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a sheet called "Main_Sheet". I have multiple tabs(East,Central) for each column value in Col_B. Every week new records are added to the main sheet. I want a google apps script function to insert new rows from Main_Sheet tab to the corresponding tabs.

**Input sheet:**

Main_Sheet

**Output_Sheets**
East
Central

Steps to be followed:
The outlined rows are new(because they do not exist in the East and Central Sheets as yet). Take these rows and paste their values in the appropriate tabs(East and Central)

[image]

**Output Sheet should look as follows:**

After running the script the highlighted rows should be added to "East" tab:

[image]

**Similarly, Central would look like:**

[image]

**Since "West" tab doesn't exist, I would like the script to create a new tab for it and insert records**

I am new to google sheets and apps script, please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your situation, how about the following sample script?

#### Sample script:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const sheets = ss.getSheets().reduce((o, s) => (o[s.getSheetName()] = s, o), {});
  const main = ss.getSheetByName("Main_Sheet");
  const [header, ...values] = main.getDataRange().getValues();
  const col = main.getLastColumn();
  const obj = values.reduce((o, r) => (o[r[1]] = o[r[1]] ? [...o[r[1]], r] : [r], o), {});
  Object.entries(obj).forEach(([s, v]) => {
    if (v.length == 0) return;
    if (sheets[s]) {
      const sheet = sheets[s];
      const temp = sheet.getDataRange().getValues().reduce((o, r) => (o[r.join("")] = true, o), {});
      const values = v.filter(r => !temp[r.join("")]);
      if (values.length > 0) {
        const lastRow = sheet.getLastRow();
        sheet.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
        main.getRange("A2:2").copyFormatToRange(sheet, 1, col, lastRow + 1, lastRow + values.length);
      }
    } else {
      const values = [header, ...v];
      const sheet = ss.insertSheet(s);
      sheet.getRange(1, 1, values.length, values[0].length).setValues(values);
      main.getRange(1, 1, 1, col).copyFormatToRange(sheet, 1, col, 1, 1);
      main.getRange("A2:2").copyFormatToRange(sheet, 1, col, 2, values.length);
    }
  });
}
```

- In this sample script, the values are retrieved from "Main_Sheet". And, retrieve each value for each sheet, and each value is put to each sheet.
- About your additional request of `Can you please include headers as well. Right now the headers are missing. Once you add headers I will test again`, I reflected it.
- About your additioanl request of `the header row is in bold values in the "Main_Sheet" tab. With your code, the headers are just being copied as plain text. I want the format of header to be same in all tabs`, I reflected it.
- About your additional request of `I am saying that I want to keep the format from the main_sheet tab consistent with other tabs. So if Main_sheet has blue and bold headers, the code should copy the header value and format into the new tab.`, I reflected it.
- About your additional request of `The goal is the paste the values from Main_Sheet to the correct tabs. The format(of header and all other rows) in main_sheet should be same as Central, East, West Tab. Right now your code is pasting plain values(it is not pasting the correct format from the Source sheet--> Main_Sheet)... Right now only header row has the correct format in the output tabs. Please preserve the format of the non header rows as well`, I reflected it.

#### Note:

- This sample script is for your showing sample Spreadsheet. So, when your Spreadsheet is changed, this script might not be able to be used. Please be careful about this.

#### References:

- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)
- [filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter)

Comment: Sorry I was confused. Actually your script worked great Tanaike. Can you please include headers as well. Right now the headers are missing. Once you add headers I will test again

Comment: @user17243359 Thank you for replying. I apologize for the inconvenience. About your additional request of `Can you please include headers as well. Right now the headers are missing. Once you add headers I will test again`, I reflected it. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize again.

Comment: Yes this works, but the format of the headers is different, is there any way to preserve the format? Right now the headers are pasting as plain values, I'd like the format for the headers and values to be the same in the main_sheet and other tabs

Comment: @user17243359 Thank you for replying. About `Yes this works, but the format of the headers is different, is there any way to preserve the format? Right now the headers are pasting as plain values, I'd like the format for the headers and values to be the same in the main_sheet and other tabs`, I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your reply. Can I ask you about the detail of it? I would like to confirm it. Unfortunately, from your question, I cannot understand `format` you expect.

Comment: Sure, the header row is in bold values with colored background in the "Main_Sheet" tab. With your code, the headers are just being copied as plain text. I want the format of header to be same in all tabs

Comment: @user17243359 Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize for the inconvenience again. Unfortunately, I couldn't notice that you wanted to set the bold type to the 1st header from your question. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. About this, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize again. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: Sorry Tanaike I think I am not explaining it properly. I am saying that I want to keep the format from the main_sheet tab consistent with other tabs. So if Main_sheet has blue and bold headers,  the code should copy the header value and format into the new tab. Does this make sense?

Comment: @user17243359 Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize for the inconvenience again. Unfortunately, I couldn't notice `I am saying that I want to keep the format from the main_sheet tab consistent with other tabs. So if Main_sheet has blue and bold headers, the code should copy the header value and format into the new tab.` from your question. This is due to my poor English skill. I deeply apologize for this. About this, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not useful, I apologize again. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: Tanaike, the header has the format preserved correctly now. but the rows copied are in plain text. I want the data rows also to have same format as source format in Main_Sheet

Comment: I cannot understand `Tanaike, the header has the format preserved correctly now. but the rows copied are in plain text. I want the data rows also to have same format as source format in Main_Sheet`. Can I ask you about your actual goal?

Comment: The goal is the paste the values from Main_Sheet to the correct tabs. The format(of header and all other rows) in main_sheet should be same as Central, East, West Tab. Right now your code is pasting plain values(it is not pasting the correct format from the Source sheet--> Main_Sheet)... Right now only header row has the correct format in the output tabs. Please preserve the format of the non header rows as well

Comment: @user17243359 When I saw your question for the 1st time, I couldn't notice that you wanted to copy the header row with the format. From your reply, I couldn't notice that you wanted to copy the format of all rows. I think that this is due to my poor English skill. About this, I have to deeply apologize for this.

Comment: @user17243359 So I'm worried that even when I modified my proposed script by your reply, you have any other requests. So in order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet including your sample input and output situations you expect? By this, I would like to prepare the sample script by correctly understanding your actual goal. I deeply apologize that I have to correctly understand your question. And also, I deeply apologize for my very poor skill.

Comment: Please see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71418993/copy-rows-with-format-from-main-tab-using-apps-script

Comment: @user17243359 Thank you for replying. About your new question, I thought that it is the duplicated question with your this question. Although unfortunately, I cannot test your actual situation and I'm not sure whether you have any other requests, using my understanding given by your replies, I updated my answer. Could you please confirm it?

Comment: This worked great Tanaike, Thank you so much for being patient and understanding my requirement.

Comment: @user17243359 Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. Thank you, too.